# Google Colab Error - SMOTE() changes names of columns (features names)

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, smote

I'm doing a binary classification, and to balance my dataset I had implement SMOTE() of sklearn in python.

In my local laptop everything runs well, but when I run it in Google Colab I get the following error:

'''IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices'''

In the computation of X_train_new variable:

```
                for score in scoring_dict.keys():
                    print (score)
                    X_train_new = X_train[scoring_dict[score][feature_tag]]
```

My code is as follows:

```
            ## Data Selection
            X_train = X.loc[(X[dx_option]==labels[0]) | (X[dx_option]==labels[1]), features]
            y_train = X.loc[(X[dx_option]==labels[0]) | (X[dx_option]==labels[1]), dx_option]

            ## Get features values ...
            in_name = 'indata.csv'
            in_path = os.path.join(save_path,in_name)
            in_label = 'inlabel.csv'
            in_pathlabel = os.path.join(save_path,in_label)
            indata = pd.DataFrame(data=X_train)
            inlabel=pd.DataFrame(y_train)
            indata.to_csv(in_path,  index=False)
            inlabel.to_csv(in_pathlabel, index=False)
            ## end of test


            smote_name = 'smote.csv'
            smote_path = os.path.join(save_path,smote_name)
            smote_label = 'smotelabel.csv'
            smote_pathlabel = os.path.join(save_path,smote_label)

            ## Data Augmentation techniques
            # SMOTE 
            sm = SMOTE(random_state=42)
            # BORDERLINE-SMOTE

            #sm =  BorderlineSMOTE(random_state=42)

            X_trains, y_trains = sm.fit_resample(X_train, y_train)
            smotedata = pd.DataFrame(data=X_trains)
            smotedatalabel=pd.DataFrame(y_trains)

            smotedata.to_csv(smote_path,  index=False)
            smotedatalabel.to_csv(smote_pathlabel, index=False)
```

I saved the X_train and y_train to detect the differences among the initial X_train and the X_trains computed with SMOTE. I found that in Google Colab I get the following file (an example):

```
         0     1      2
   0   0.232 2.545  0.443
   1   0.565 1.567  0.235
```

While in my laptop I get:

```
           area   volume  tt_feature 
   0      0.232   2.545  0.443
   1      0.565   1.567  0.235
```

Why different machines saves list differently?

Comment: If your machine is Python2 and since Colaboratory is Python3, results of division may have changed from integer to float, and if you use these to index an array, it'll produce the above error. If you have division which is supposed to produce integers to be used as array indices, make sure it's with `//` and not `/`.

Comment: @BarakItkin, my machine is Python3, but I will check the results of the division. Thanks